# Mask div using CSS

Tags: html, css, mask, masking

Ok so say i'm using the follow setup for my divs:

`.background` will contain an image.
`.overlay` will have a semitransparent white background for the overlay
`.inner` would effectively mask out a rectangle the size of the div? So that the background is transparent and cuts through the overlay div.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with just css?

Comment: Could you define `mask out a rectangle` please.. It's not very clear what you mean..

Comment: Could you add an example screenshot?

Comment: Don't understand what you want? please add some working example.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8hxoh58r/

Comment: Using @Jacques Marais fiddle as a starting point, I think you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/a8xsmrca/ ?

Comment: @deebs Oh, I see now.

Comment: @deebs thanks for the comment yeh deebs that is exactly what i getting at!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can achieve that adding a thick border with some opacity [(Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/s463vtyt/).  The border widths will determine size of rectangle desired:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg');
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 130px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 130px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-left: 100px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-right: 100px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

YES, if you use a PNG image for the masking. It is possible to clip the background div using it's children. What you would need to do it use a PNG with transparent area in the middle or where ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't mask complex shapes, you can mask simple shapes like a cube or their rounded edges.

Just use:
`overflow-x`
or
`overflow-y`
or
`overflow`

Which according to an inspect of Google Chrome, can be set to:
`auto`, `hidden`, `inherit`, `initial`, `overlay`, `revert`, `scroll`, `unset`, or `visible`

Although, I find that:
`inherit`, `initial`, `revert`, `unset` and `visible`
do not provide a mask in most cases.

Finally, if you want to mask on a curve, simply set a `border-radius` property.
Remember, in a `border-radius`, you can use:

1 value: A; all corners

2 values: A, B; A=Top-Left & Bottom-Right B=Top-Right & Bottom-Left

3 values: A, B, C; A=Top-Left B=Top-Right & Bottom-Left C=Bottom-Right

4 values: A, B, C, D; A=Top-Left B=Top-Right C=Bottom-Right D=Bottom-Left

[image: example of unmasked div]
[image: example of overflow: hidden]
[image: Example of overflow: hidden, border-radius: 100%]

-tested in Google Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit) with HTML and CSS on the date of this posting.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - no, you could not clip div by it's children.

But you can solve your problem without clipping. As I understand, you just need white border around inner div. You may use border or box-shadow. Also you can create such border with 4 divs on each side